# Django: how can i assosiate multiple groups to one file?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a "File" table which could have multiple groups associated with it. How can i implement that with django?

```
groups = models.ForeignKey(Group)
```

This will enable me to only have one group for each file. I thought about creating a CharField with group names separated by a colon or a comma if there's no other way.

Answer (score 1):

Use [many-to-many relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships)

eg:

```
class File(models.Model):
    ...

class Group(models.Model):
    files = models.ManyToManyField(File, related_name='groups')
```

Comment: Yeah i saw that earlier but i couldn't quite understand the examples. But your example made it clear. Thanks.